# Elantech touchpad annoying behaviour (gestures don't work well)

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, 17.10, multi-touch, elantech

I am having problems with my Touchpad Elantech on Acer Aspire E1-572G. I tried both Ubuntu 16 and 17 (and also other Linux distros), but no luck.
My problem is that the gestures (two-finger tap for right click and two-finger scroll) are actually working, but not in a smooth way. For example, on average, I have to do the two-finger tap 2 or 3 times before I get it right, and I have to be VERY careful to hit the pad with the two fingers exactly in the same time, other wise it doesn't work. It's annoying and it slows me down a lot.

I just switched from Windows 10 and over there the touchpad gestures were a LOT smoother, never had to do them more than one time.
I'm wondering if there's any possibility to use the Windows drivers on Ubuntu, or any other workaround.

Thanks!

EDIT: my lsusb output:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2c54 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04ca:300b Lite-On Technology Corp. Atheros 
AR3012 Bluetooth
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

EDIT2: here's a video comparison of my Elantech touchpad on Windows 10 and on Ubuntu 17.10, to clearify what my problem is: https://youtu.be/L6SBWJpAT5A

Scrolling is laggy and it doesn't always work, positioning the pointer for small movements is difficult, and the two-finger tap for right click is almost unusable.

Comment: perhaps the output of  'lsusb' would be useful in determining exactly what your issue is. Please [edit] that into your question. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: so... nothing? no suggestions? no solutions? i can't believe to be the only one to have this problem...